# Count longest continuous sequence of captial letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far my code finds any capital letters in any input from stdin.

I am curious to find how to find the longest sequence and only print that. I am currently lost on how to implement a counter to count the longest capital letter sequence.

For example an input could be `"AbcEDFG"` - All it should print `"EDFG"` as that is the longest continuous sequence of capital letters.

```
import sys

def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        s=""
        lines = list(line.strip())
        for c in lines:
            if c.isupper():
                s += c
        print(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You just accumulate all the capital letters here. You should keep a variable that records the longest so far, and clear `s` at each iteration.
Try implement it as a function of a single line, without iterating on stdin.

Comment: BTW the line `lines = list(line.strip())` can be omitted without any effect. also, the name `lines` is a misnomer. It should be simply `line`, singular. or `chars`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
max(re.findall('[A-Z]+', line), key=len)
```

Comment: That works but is there another way from the code that I have provided?